# How to run a command on all results of find?

Tags: unix, find

Using *find* I create a file that contains all the files that use a specific key word:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -l 'foo' > foo.txt
```

I want to take that list in foo.txt and maybe run some commands using that list, i.e. run an `ls` command on the list contained within the file.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `xargs` to create `foo.txt`. Just execute the command with `-exec` like this:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l 'foo' {} \; > foo.txt
```

Then you can run `ls` against the file by looping through the file:

```
while IFS= read -r read file
do
   ls "$file"
done < foo.txt
```

---

Maybe it is a little ugly, but this can also make it:

```
ls $(cat foo.txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xargs` like this:

```
xargs ls < foo.txt
```

The advantage of xargs is that it will execute the command with multiple arguments which is more efficient than executing the command once per argument using a loop, for example.